# Team Foundation Server 2017 Build and Release

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, ms-release-management

I'm trying to setup TFS 2017 in my company. 
Everything is fine until I came to release tab. 
I'm little bit confused.

How on earth I need to deploy everything to my local server. I read a lot of articles regarding this but still confused how to use artifacts.
Right now I have setted up source control and created build definition and stuck on release.

Anybody manage to setup release in TFS 2015 or 2017? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [article](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/08/an-asp-net-mvc-site-thats-easy-to-deploy-from-a-tfs-build/) that explains how to build and deploy web project on premise. Hope this will help somebody.

Need to use this arguments in Visual Studio Build task

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish 
/p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True 
/p:publishUrl=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\for-deploy\website
```

It will create in Artifacts folder with website that can be simply copied to remote machine in Release definition.

Answer (score 1):

You should view artifacts as single deploy able packages, so if your application has a front end website and a database you can package them up the website as one artifact and the database as another during the build.  When it comes to a release, your release could deploy the website to one server and the database to another or even the same server, the choice is yours. I tend to have development environments hosted on a single server but pre-production and production are load balanced, the only change from development to production is the name of the server to deploy the change to.

Comment: It is all theory.I'm looking for practical example of using artifact in the right way.

Comment: it all depends on what your requirements are, the answer is fairly simple an artefact is something that is deployed somewhere, it could be the whole application or components of a system.